# Empty space on side of page when using width: 100%

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I've seen tons of entries about this, and have looked at as many as I can, and none have resolved my issue. The following is the relevant CSS for my page:

```
html, body
{
    background-color:#E9E9E9;
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    #messageListing {
        width: 70%;
        font-family: Arial;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 15%;
        padding-right: 15%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #messageListing {
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Arial;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
}

    #messageListing > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0px;
    }

            @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
                #messageListing > ul > li > .messageEntry > .messageTitle {
                    width: 100%;
                    display: inline-block;
                    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#303844, #262c36); /* For Safari */
                    background: -o-linear-gradient(#303844, #262c36); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
                    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#303844, #262c36); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
                    background: linear-gradient(#4D545C, #303338); /* Standard syntax */
                    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4D545C', endColorstr='#303338',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    padding: 5px 10px;
                    border-top: 1px solid black;
                    border-left: 1px solid black;
                    border-right: 1px solid black;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                    margin-bottom: -4px;
                }
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
                #messageListing > ul > li > .messageEntry > .messageTitle {
                    width: 100%;
                    display: inline-block;
                    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#303844, #262c36); /* For Safari */
                    background: -o-linear-gradient(#303844, #262c36); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
                    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#303844, #262c36); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
                    background: linear-gradient(#4D545C, #303338); /* Standard syntax */
                    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4D545C', endColorstr='#303338',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
                    color: #FFFFFF;
                    font-size: 70%;
                    padding: 2px 4px;
                    border-top: 1px solid black;
                    border-left: 1px solid black;
                    border-right: 1px solid black;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                    margin-bottom: -4px;
                }
            }

            #messageListing > ul > li > .messageEntry > .messageTitle > .messageInfo {
                width:100%;
            }

            #messageListing > ul > li > .messageEntry > .messageTitle > .messageBadge {
                float: right;
            }

            .messageDate {
                float: right;
            }

            @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
                #messageListing > ul > li > .messageEntry > .messageText {
                    width: 100%;
                    display: inline-block;
                    padding: 5px 10px;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                    border-left: 1px solid black;
                    border-right: 1px solid black;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                }
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
                #messageListing > ul > li > .messageEntry > .messageText {
                    width: 100%;
                    display: inline-block;
                    font-size: 70%;
                    padding: 2px 4px;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                    border-left: 1px solid black;
                    border-right: 1px solid black;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;
                }
            }

#postDiscussionForm {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Things I've checked and tried thus far:

- Checking HTML file for any and all width stuff, removing it, checking again. No padding or margin stuff there, nor anything defining width by static pixel values.
- Using overflow-x: hidden;, as it just disallowed side scrolling but the 100% width messages were still cut off.
- Setting media queries width stuff to percentages instead of pixels.

Also, it should be noted that I'm using VS2012 with MVC, and regarding that, I also checked the shared .cshtml files for anything, as well as the Site.css file, nothing helped. If need more from me, let me know, thanks!

Also, [as seen in the Inspect view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMXhP.png), the space takes place even outside the encompassing HTML tag, so that's even more confusing to me.

[Another view of the inspect view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuAlB.png), this showing that the messages are somehow extending beyond the window frame. Anyone have any idea how that'd happen?

EDIT: Here's an SSCCE of the HTML and anything else that may assist:

**Details.cshtml**

```
<div id="messageListing">
    <ul></ul>
</div>

.....................................
/* irrelevant JS */
.....................................

if (loginType == "pharmadmin" || loginType == "pharm") {

                $.getJSON("/api/Message/", function (messagesJsonPayload) {
                    $(messagesJsonPayload).each(function (i, item) {
                        if (item.NDC == '@Model.Item1.NDC') {
                            var badge = '';
                            // Check (if user logged in) if unread, update DrugVisit entry
                            if (loginType == "pharmadmin") {
                                if (dateLastSeen != null) {
                                    if (item.Date > dateLastSeen) {
                                        badge = '<img style="padding-right:5px;" src="/Images/message_badge_large.png">';
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    badge = '<img style="padding-right:5px;" src="/Images/message_badge_large.png">';
                                }
                            }
                            $("#messageListing > ul").append('<li><div class="messageEntry"><div class="messageTitle"> \
                                                        ' + '<div class="messageInfo">' + badge + item.User + '<span class="messageDate">' + formatDateForOutput(item.Date) + '</span></div>' + '\
                                                        ' + '<div class="messageBadge">' + '</div></div>' + ' \
                                                        ' + '<div class="messageText">' + item.Text + '</div></div>' + ' \
                                                         </li>');
                        }
                    }
                    );

                    if ($(messagesJsonPayload).length <= 0) {
                        $("#messageListing").prepend("No discussion has been posted for this shortage.");
                    }
                    $(".messagePosting").show();
                });
            }
```

The code shown grabs the messages for the current page and creates the HTML for each of them, which it inserts into the messageListing . Anything else needed, let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: The HTML would be nice to have as well as it stands, the code is a bit incomplete, it's hard to troubleshoot if you do not have the full code.

Comment: @IllimarPihlamäe: It's 300 lines of stuff, should I post anyway? It's half JS for graphing and message posting, and 99% of it would be irrelevant to the question. Not being lazy, just wanna be considerate.

Comment: @Befall - You should create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: @Alohci - I'll do my best, but due to the nature of MVC, I have the current HTML page, the shared layout page, the style.css AND the Site.css page as well. I have no idea how to trim it all down. :\

Comment: You should really isolate the issue like Alohci said, but failing that the full MVC output is not that bad, currently it's better than nothing.

Comment: @IllimarPihlamäe - I added an SSCCE of the HTML generation stuff, let me know if it helps or if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Use the F-12 Developer tools (in IE - although all good browsers have them) and use the 'Select Element' option to see which item is truly 'limiting' your content.  Then you can also try and just put some random element like a table to ensure there is content to actually 'fill' to the space you require.  That should give you a good start.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to put that there. I'll edit it in, but here, as you can see it's outside all of the HTML parts: http://i.imgur.com/f1R3bBu.png

Answer (score 0):

Note that the [HTML box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) for padding can be un-intuitive if you're not familiar with it. `padding` is applied *on top of* `width` so if you have `width: 100%;` as well as `padding: 5px 10px;` on an element that is a direct child of `<body>` then the entire element will extend beyond the browser window causing the space on the side of the page and causing the scrollbars to appear.

I think this may be what is happening in your case. Here is a JS Fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/9uFtV/2/

If you want to change the box model so that `width` refers to the width of content+padding rather than just the width of the content you can use `box-sizing: border-box;` in your CSS rules. [Here's some further reading on the topic](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Comment: I'll edit this in, but here's an inspect of my page, you'll notice it's something in the message stuff that's doing it, right? Nothing else extends beyond the barrier, and I have no idea how this would. http://i.imgur.com/vyPw2Qh.png